# How to insert data in encrypted varbinary field from flat file using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a table called **demo** with three fields.

```
ID int identity,
Name varbinary(128),
orderdate datetime
```

Demo table has the field 'Name' which is encrypted.

Now I have a flat file which has data like

```
1,John,2016-01-01
```

**How would I go about achieving this in SSIS?**

In TSQL, I can enter data like this

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT

DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT_ASYM

INSERT INTO dbo.Demo (Name,OrderDate)
SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('STORE_CRYPT'),'John'),GETDATE()

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest and fastest way is to use a staging table where data is stored as varchar, then add an execute SQL Task that perform the encryption and insert data into the destination table.

*Staging table structure*

```
ID int identity,
Name varchar(255),
orderdate datetime
```

*Execute SQL Task Command*

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT

DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT_ASYM

INSERT INTO dbo.Demo (Name,OrderDate)
SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('STORE_CRYPT'),Name),OrderDate 
FROM StagingTable

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT
```

---

**Other possible solution**  *(not sure if it works)*

Try using an OLEDB Command transformation instead of OLEDB Destination and use the following command: *(Note that from performance perspective it is not recommended to use OLEDB command)*

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT

DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT_ASYM

INSERT INTO dbo.Demo (Name,OrderDate)
SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('STORE_CRYPT'),?),?

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY STORE_CRYPT
```

And map the `Name` column to the first parameter and `Orderdate` to the second

Comment: Thank you. it worked as you mentioned. I created a global temp table first. Data into global temp table next and then execute sql task to get data into the table with encrypted columns. Thanks again.